# Python string replacement

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to replace the occurrence of a word with another:

```
word_list = { "ugh" : "disappointed"}

tmp = ['laughing ugh']

for index, data in enumerate(tmp):
    for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
        if key in data:
            tmp[index]=data.replace(key, word_list[key])

print tmp
```

Whereas this works... the occurrence of `ugh` in `laughing` is also being replaced in the output: `ladisappointeding disappointed.`

How does one avoid this so that the output is `laughing disappointed`?

Comment: Split the string on spaces. Only replace exact matches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, you may want to consider to replace word by word.

**Example:**

```
word_list = { "ugh" : "disappointed"}
tmp = ['laughing ugh']

for t in tmp:
    words = t.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] in word_list.keys():
            words[i] = word_list[words[i]]
    newline = " ".join(words)
    print(newline)
```

**Output:**

```
laughing disappointed
```

**Step-by-Step Explanations:**

1. Get every sentence in the tmp `list`:

   ```
   for t in tmp:
   ```
2. split the sentence into `words`:

   ```
   words = t.split()
   ```
3. check whether any `word` in `words` are  in the `word_list` `keys`. If it does, replace it with its `value`:

   ```
   for i in range(len(words)):
       if words[i] in word_list.keys():
           words[i] = word_list[words[i]]
   ```
4. rejoin the replaced words and print the result out:

   ```
   newline = " ".join(words)
   print(newline)
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using a RegEx:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bugh\b', 'disappointed', 'laughing ugh')
'laughing disappointed'
```

The `\b` stands for a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.sub`:

```
for key, value in word_list.items():
    tmp = re.sub("\\b{}\\b".format(key), value, tmp[index])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
word_list = { "ugh" : "disappointed", "123" : "lol"}
tmp = ['laughing 123 ugh']

for word in tmp:
    words = word.split()
for i in words[:]:
    if  i in word_list.keys():
    replace_value = word_list.get(i)
    words[words.index(i)] = replace_value
output = " ".join(words)
print output
```

This code will swap each key of the dict (so the word you want to replace ) with the dict value of that key ( the word you want it to be replaced with) in every case and with multiple values!

```
Output:
    laughing lol disappointed
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

for index, data in enumerate(tmp):
    for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
        if key in data:
            pattern = '\b' + key + '\b'
            data = re.sub(pattern, value, data)
            tmp[index] = data
```

Side note: you need `data = ...` line (to overwrite `data` variable) otherwise it will work incorrectly when `word_list` contains multiple entries.

Answer (score 1):

Fast:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: word_list.get(m.group(), m.group()), t) 
     for t in tmp]
['laughing disappointed']
>>>
```

Very Fast:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(word_list.keys()), lambda m: word_list.get(m.group(), m.group()), t) 
...  for t in tmp]
['laughing disappointed']
>>>
```